# How to send message through django-channels from asyncio loop with add_reader

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, django-channels

I am trying to listen for notifications from postgres database and send message through django-channels on each row insertion, for that I want to use asyncio loop, where I am adding reader for connection.

However, I am receiving following error on attempt to use `async_to_sync`: `RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.`

Here is my code:

```py
import asyncio
import logging

import channels.layers
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import connections

channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        conns = [(connections[db].cursor().connection, db) for db in settings.DATABASES]

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        for conn, db in conns:
            conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("LISTEN event_changed;")

            loop.add_reader(conn, partial(self.handle_notify, conn=conn, db=db))

        logger.info("Starting runlistener loop.")
        loop.run_forever()

    def handle_notify(self, conn, db):
        conn.poll()
        for notify in conn.notifies:
            logger.debug(f"new event received on db {db}: {notify.payload}.")
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                db, {"type": "on_new_event", "event": notify.payload}
            )
        conn.notifies.clear()
```

I can't use `await` in `handle_notify` since it is not async function and I couldn't find any way to use async function as a callback for `add_reader`.

I've managed to implement this functionality without asyncio, by simply checking connection with `select.select` in a while loop (in threads per database), but are there any solutions to overcome the issue with asyncio?